# Editing norvig's scheme interpreter for python

Tags: python, scheme, racket

I'm trying to edit Norvig's [lispy.py](https://norvig.com/lispy2.html) scheme-to-python interpreter for a racket program in which, in addition to the procedures he includes, I use `open-input-string` and `string-replace`.

It looked like I could just add the corresponding python definitions into his `add_globals()` function, which I did, as follows.

```
    def add_globals(self):
        "Add some Scheme standard procedures."
        import math, cmath, operator as op
        self.update(vars(math))
        self.update(vars(cmath))
        self.update({
         '+':op.add, '-':op.sub, '*':op.mul, '/':op.div, 'not':op.not_, 
         '>':op.gt, '<':op.lt, '>=':op.ge, '<=':op.le, '=':op.eq, 
         'equal?':op.eq, 'eq?':op.is_, 'length':len, 'cons':cons,
         'car':lambda x:x[0], 'cdr':lambda x:x[1:], 'append':op.add,  
         'list':lambda *x:list(x), 'list?': lambda x:isa(x,list),
         'null?':lambda x:x==[], 'symbol?':lambda x: isa(x, Symbol),
         'boolean?':lambda x: isa(x, bool), 'pair?':is_pair, 
         'port?': lambda x:isa(x,file), 'apply':lambda proc,l: proc(*l), 
         'eval':lambda x: eval(expand(x)), 'load':lambda fn: load(fn), 'call/cc':callcc,
         'open-input-file':open,'close-input-port':lambda p: p.file.close(), 
         'open-output-file':lambda f:open(f,'w'), 'close-output-port':lambda p: p.close(),
         'eof-object?':lambda x:x is eof_object, 'read-char':readchar, 
        #  Additions below
         'open-input-string':lambda x:x.decode('string_escape'),
         'string-replace':lambda strng,x,y: strng.replace(x, y),
        #  Additions above
         'read':read, 'write':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(to_string(x)),
         'display':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(x if isa(x,str) else to_string(x))})
        return self
```

However, when I try to use the racket functions in question, I get the following error from norvig's lispy repl:

```
    % python lispy.py
    Lispy version 2.0
    lispy> (define (ex s)
      (read (open-input-string (string-replace (string-replace s "\'" "\"") "," ""))))
    lispy> (define inputlistsliceexample
      (ex "[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]"))
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'next_token'
    lispy>
```

Then, if I get rid of my use of `open-input-string` in the definition for `ex`, I get the following interaction:

```
    % python lispy.py
    Lispy version 2.0
    lispy> (define (exnihilo s)
      (string-replace (string-replace s "\'" "\"") "," ""))    
    lispy> (define inputlistsliceexample
      (exnihilo "[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]"))
    lispy> inputsliceexample
    LookupError: inputsliceexample
```

Presumably I'm oversimplifying the process, but before I really dig into the rest lispy.py, I'd like to ask here to see whether the bug is superficially visible in what I added.

## Edit:

Here are is my current add_globals:

```
    def add_globals(self):
        "Add some Scheme standard procedures."
        import math, cmath, operator as op
        self.update(vars(math))
        self.update(vars(cmath))
        self.update({
         '+':op.add, '-':op.sub, '*':op.mul, '/':op.div, 'not':op.not_, 
         '>':op.gt, '<':op.lt, '>=':op.ge, '<=':op.le, '=':op.eq, 
         'equal?':op.eq, 'eq?':op.is_, 'length':len, 'cons':cons,
         'car':lambda x:x[0], 'cdr':lambda x:x[1:], 'append':op.add,  
         'list':lambda *x:list(x), 'list?': lambda x:isa(x,list),
         'null?':lambda x:x==[], 'symbol?':lambda x: isa(x, Symbol),
         'boolean?':lambda x: isa(x, bool), 'pair?':is_pair, 
         'port?': lambda x:isa(x,file), 'apply':lambda proc,l: proc(*l), 
         'eval':lambda x: eval(expand(x)), 'load':lambda fn: load(fn), 'call/cc':callcc,
         'open-input-file':open,'close-input-port':lambda p: p.file.close(), 
         'open-output-file':lambda f:open(f,'w'), 'close-output-port':lambda p: p.close(),
         'eof-object?':lambda x:x is eof_object, 'read-char':readchar, 
        #  Additions below
         'string->jsexpr':lambda x: json.loads(x),
         'string-replace':lambda strng,x,y: strng.replace(x, y),
        #  Additions above
         'read':read, 'write':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(to_string(x)),
         'display':lambda x,port=sys.stdout:port.write(x if isa(x,str) else to_string(x))})
        return self
```

In the lispy repl, `string-replace` seems to succeed:

```
    % python lispy.py
    Lispy version 2.0
    lispy> (string-replace "[['Noth', '<b>ing</b>'], ' in']" "\'" "\"")
    "[[\"Noth\", \"<b>ing</b>\"], \" in\"]"
    lispy>
```

However when, at the end of lispy.py, I run

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        x = eval(parse("""(begin
        (string-replace "[['Noth', '<b>ing</b>'], ' in']" "\'" "\"")
        )
        """
        ))
    
        print x
```

instead of running this (which is how the file came),

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        repl()
```

the program hangs — and when I trace it, I see that there's an infinite loop.

Any ideas? (This is, I think, a more specific problem than my first one... I'm definitely feeling closer...)

Comment: Answered the question posted in my "edit" section. I needed to add an extra backslash to escape the escape in the triple quoted section, like this: `"""(begin (string-replace "[['Noth', '<b>ing</b>'], ' in']" "\\'" "\\""))"""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense that you cannot find variable `inputsliceexample`, because the variable you defined is named `inputlistsliceexample`. So your `string-replace` has worked fine. I'm not sure about your problem with `open-input-string`, but from the link you posted it looks to me like `read` takes in a file or a port or something like that, while your `open-input-string` returns a string.

Comment: Thanks for the typo catch. I ended up getting around the open-input-string problem by using the racket `string->jsexpr` procedure instead of `open-input-string`. So, in lispy, I just imported json and defined `string->jsexpr` like this `'string->jsexpr':lambda x: json.loads(x)`. It was indeed after all simpler than I feared and suspected it would be.

Comment: Still broken though! It seems to work in the lispy repl, but not when I run it with `eval(parse(`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you were replacing single-quotes with double-quotes, it'll have no change on example given.  But yea, came to the same conclusion, just putting this here so others can see how it would be written.

```
(define (ex s) (open-input-string (string-replace s "," "")))
(define inputlistsliceexample (ex "[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]"))
inputlistsliceexample
```

"[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]"

```
(define (exnihilo s) (string-replace s "," ""))
(define inputlistsliceexample (exnihilo "[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]"))
inputlistsliceexample
```

"[0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0]"